# Filter existing array for objects not appearing in a different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a newbie and I am trying to create a new array from an existing array but only keep the object when a property of the object doesn't appear in another array...

```
 ticketDetailsSubset2 = ticketDetailsArray.filter((i) => {
            !excludeTickets.includes(i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0]);
          });
```

- **ticketDetailsArray**=the main array
- **ticketDetailsSubset2**= the new array I want to create
- **excludeTickets**=the array containing ticket numbers..

If the `i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0]` is in the exclude Tickets array then don't include it in the new array...

Here's the array of exclude Tickets..

```
[Array(1)]0: ["0017522827238"]
```

The array of ticket Details Array is pretty big but here's a snippet...

```
0: {$: {…}, stl19:OriginalTicketDetails: Array(1), stl19:TransactionIndicator: Array(1), stl19:TicketNumber: Array(1), stl19:PassengerName: Array(1), …}
1: {$: {…}, stl19:OriginalTicketDetails: Array(1), stl19:TransactionIndicator: Array(1), stl19:TicketNumber: Array(1), stl19:PassengerName: Array(1), …}
2:
$: {id: "90", index: "3", elementId: "pnr-90"}
stl19:AgencyLocation: ["29JB"]
stl19:AgentSine: ["A46"]
stl19:DutyCode: ["*"]
stl19:OriginalTicketDetails: ["TE 0017522827239-AT YOASH/N 29JB*A46 1439/16APR "]
stl19:PassengerName: ["CLAUS/M"]
stl19:PaymentType: [""]
stl19:TicketNumber: ["0017522827239"]
stl19:Timestamp: ["2021-04-16T14:39:00"]
stl19:TransactionIndicator: ["TE"]
```

The problem is the array returned has no rows. At least one of the stl19:TicketNumber is NOT in the exclude Tickets array and therefore should be returned. If the condition is false I wanted the object returned.
There's no error but it's not evaluating the filter with the condition clause. I'm a beginner so sorry if this is a js 101 question.

Comment: missing return statem with curly brackets, it should be `(i) => !excludeTickets.includes(i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0])` without curly or with return statement and curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function expects to receive a function in the parameter that returns a boolean.

> If you want to know more about the filter function [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Looking at your code, we can see that you passed a void callback function (which has no return), I believe that the example below solves your problem:

```
 ticketDetailsSubset2 = ticketDetailsArray.filter((i) => {
   return !excludeTickets.includes(i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0]);
 });
```

You can also use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), sample code:

```
ticketDetailsArray.filter((i) => !excludeTickets.includes(i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0]));
```

Comment: In this case it is difficult to know if the signature of the object is correct, but considering that it is already using this code, I am assuming that it is.
In the case of the code reported by the author, what is missing is the return in the function

Comment: checking 0017522827238 and return value=false
checking 0017522827239 and return value=false

```
I changed it to this.

ticketDetailsSubset2 = ticketDetailsArray.filter((i: any) => {
            console.log(
              `checking ${
                i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0]
              } and return value=${excludeTickets.includes(
                i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0]
              )}`
            );

            return !excludeTickets.includes(i["stl19:TicketNumber"][0]);
          });
```
Why is the return value false for "0017522827238". it's in the exclude

Comment: whoops, sorry don't know how to make the comment code in a reply obviously-duh

Comment: Your direction sounds like it would work but it's not working. Which is strange. I will re-post and try and better demonstrate.